# Flutter How to put PageView and ExpansionTile in one Row

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, row, flutter-pageview

I have a design like this:
[image]

How can I put PageView and ExpansionTile widgets in a one Row. Row expanded by ExpansionTile's height and PageView must expand by Row's height.

Comment: may you just need to wrap with `Expanded` widget. can you include what you;ve tried so far

Comment: Unfortunately, Expanded doesn't work :-(

Comment: Can you include what you;ve tried so far?